# pfSense: how to route traffic to a specific network via ipsec

Tags: pfsense, route

We have pfSense 2.60 with one ip public

We have a working ipsec tunnel to a customer FortiGate

I need to be able to force routing of packets to/from 10.68.245.200/29 via ipsec interface

> we cannot ping 10.68.245.201 from pfSense shell and customer's IT service is NOT blocking pings

Narrowed question: **What step should I do to be route traffic  to/from 10.68.245.200/29 via ipsec ?**

More general goal: I need *all* traffic from *every* and *each hosts* directed to 10.68.245.200/29 must be routed via ipsec tunnel.

I was supposing to find IPSec as interface to be used as a gateway, but in the route definition panel I can see only WAN, LAN1 and LAN2, no ipsec.

All other traffic must be routed (as actually) via WAN

### EDIT 1:

I cannot use VTI, because 3rd party doesn't allow it

### EDIT 2:

I cannot change the customer's policy about phase 2.

I need to resolve only by my side

- I have to force traffic to be routed to ipsec if target net matches, second,
- And I must translate ip from local to assigned ips when usin ipsec and/or when target net matches

I have no idea on how to do both.

Please, so, explain my the first: What step should I do to be route traffic to/from 10.68.245.200/29 via ipsec ?

pfSense itself is not able to ping 10.68.245.201
How can I be able to allow pfSense to ping 10.68.245.201 ?

- I need to exit through ipsec
- I need to present pfSense using an ipaddress in 10.68.245.192/29

Answer (score 2):

There are generally two ways to do IPsec site-to-site VPNs:

- Using Virtual tunnel interfaces (VTI) which Cisco and many others call *route-based* VPN. You use the natural IP routing mechanism to direct traffic into the VPN, by assigning the tunnel interface as the next hop.
- Using IKE traffic selectors which Cisco and others call *policy-based*. You declare which source/destination address range combinations will flow across the VPN as part of the VPN config, rather than using routes.

Do you know which type you have here? If you have the latter (policy based) then that explains the lack of an IPsec interface to use in routing. Instead, you would need to adjust the Phase 2 Entries under the VPN settings and ensure you have one with the local subnet set as 0.0.0.0/0 (i.e. everything) and the remote as 10.68.245.200/29.

Both ends need to agree on the traffic selectors, so if you can't use 0.0.0.0/0 because the other end does not want to send everything from 10.68.245.200/29 to you, you need to split it down to the actual address ranges you are using and ensure the far end mirrors that configuration. If your addresses clash with others the customer needs to be able to route to independently, or you don't have the freedom to configure the traffic selectors on the far end, you have to start thinking about NAT - https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/vpn/ipsec/phase-2-nat.html for the pfSense side.

Comment: I cannot use VTI, because 3rd party doesn't support it.
Could you expand the part about IKE traffice selector? i've a pfSense firewall

Comment: If I use local subnet set as 0.0.0.0/0 , the customer's FW is not accepting phase 2. So I've local subnet as 10.68.245.192/29

Comment: Added another paragraph to the answer. I assume you're wanting to send traffic from _more_ than just 10.68.245.192/29, i.e. elsewhere in your network?

Comment: Only 2 ip, on 2 different lans, need to comunicate to 10.68.245.200/29

Comment: What are the two different LANs? You just need to make a P2 entry for each. The important part is making sure the opposite side matches - do you have control of the customer Fortigate?

Comment: I cannot change the customer's policy about phase 2. So i need to resolve in some way doing 2 things: first, I have to force traffic to be routed to ipsec  if target net matches, second, I must translate ip from local to assigned ips when usin ipsec and/or when target  net matches

Comment: Ok I think I understand now. Sounds like you will have to NAT on the pfSense box, yes. I am not sure on the detail until I get a chance to look at my own installation later.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to define matching but inverse qualifying policies on each end of the VPN tunnel as shown in these examples:

https://getlabsdone.com/how-to-configure-ipsec-site-to-site-vpn-between-fortigate-and-pfsense/

https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/recipes/ipsec-s2s-psk.html

Comment: Sorry, as state in the OP, I cannot change the customer's policy about phase 2. But thanks for pointing an alternative

Comment: If you cannot change the phase 2 policy then it will never work without 'hiding' the second network using NAT but you may run afoul of security policies and possible even criminal considerations by doing that.

Comment: I need to NAT, I am pretty sure. But I am translating 2 lan IPs into other 2 (different) lan IPs, why could it be criminal? 
Anyway, we cannot change customer's policy.

Comment: Because the inability to change the policy on the other end of the tunnel usuall implies that they do not know about it, that you are accessing the protected network from a network they did not give you permission to include in the tunnel. I'm not saying it is a criminal act, but it could be a serious problem if you do it without their permission.

Comment: I am in the opposite situation. Customer assigned two server to call and want we present our server as we are in a specific subnet. I am facing the customer requests. I am not doing anything unauthorized

Comment: If it is the customer's request then they should be able to easily modify their tunnel policy configuration to allow the additional IP networks through the tunnel and there will be no need for NAT.

Comment: I know buy the don't want to do. Every and each supplier of this customer is actually doing this magic IP translation

Comment: Ah so then yes you are stuck doing the NAT configuration. More work for you to save them doing the work.

Comment: Should I delete this question and/or reask explicitly how to do this kind of NAT?

Comment: You can leave the question and make a new one if you can't find good documentation on how to do NAT on PFSense. I think it should be well documented. Search for PFSense VPN with IP Overlap. The design for IP overlap is to allow a network on one side of the tunnel or the other to use NAT to overcome the issue of an overlap of the same IP addresses in the protected networks on both ends of the tunnel.

Comment: I tried to set local to my lan and nat to remote lan network / 29 , but remote tunnel do not connects phase 2. Only phase 2 settings with local set to 10.68.245.129 / 29 is able to  connect. I start to think it's a config problem of 3rd party. Is it possibile that remote party refuses phase 2 if a nat is enabled?

Comment: Possible yes, though difficult. Basically without their participation and troubleshooting, you will never know. You have to match their side configuration.